# Negative and positive return values of compare and compareTo

Tags: java, return-value, comparable, compareto

I read that the rule for the return value of these methods is that for obj1.compareTo(obj2) for example, if obj2 is under obj1 in the hierarchy, the return value is **negative** and if it's on top of obj1, then it's **positive** (and if it's equal then it's 0). However, in my class I saw examples where Math.signum was used in order to get -1 (for negative) and 1 (for positive) in the compareTo method.

Is there any reason for that?

---

EDIT:

Here is the code I meant:

```
Comparator comp = new Comparator() {
   public int compare(Object obj1, Object obj2) {
       Book book1 = (Book) obj1;
       Book book2 = (Book) obj2;

       int order = book1.getAuthor().compareTo(book2.getAuthor());
       if (order  == 0) {
          order = (int) Math.signum(book1.getPrice() - book2.getPrice());
       }
   return order;
};
```

Comment: Sorry that I added it after

Comment: Probably price have float or double type. If so it is almost correct implementation. Because if you just write `(int)book1.getPrice() - book2.getPrice()` you can get overflow. almost because it is possible truble with equality of floating point types.

Comment: @talex And if you write `(int)(book1.getPrice() - book2.getPrice())`, small differences will be incorrectly rounded to zero.

Comment: @biziclop yes. I didn't saw obvious problem :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is there any reason for using **Math.signum**

**Yes** there is.

```
order = (int) Math.signum(book1.getPrice() - book2.getPrice());
```

Suppose you have replace the above line with this

```
order = (int)(book1.getPrice() - book2.getPrice());
```

Now let us assume

```
book1.getPrice() returns 10.50 
book2.getPrice() returns  10.40
```

If you do not use **signum** you will never have any compile time or run time error but value of **order** will be 0. This implies that book1 is equals to book2 which is logically false.

But if you use **signum** value of **order** will be 1 which implies book1 > book2.

But it must be mentioned that you should never make any assumption about compare function returning value between 1 and -1.
You can read official document for comparator http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html.

Answer (score 1):

Any negative number will do to show that a < b.  And any positive number will show that a > b.  -1 and 1 serve that purpose just fine.  There's no sense of being "more less than" or "more greater than"; they are binary attributes.  The reason that any negative (or positive) value is permitted is probably historical; for integers it's common to implement the comparator by simple subtraction.

Answer (score 1):

No.

**PS**: Frequent error in implementation is to use subtraction

```
public int compareTo(Object o) {
     OurClass other = (OurClass)o; //Skip type check

     return this.intField - other.intField;
}
```

It is wrong because if you call `new OurClass(Integer.MIN_VALUE).compareTo(new OurClass(Integer.MAX_VALUE))` you get overflow. Probably `Math.abs` is attempt (failed) to deal with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The only reason I can see is that if you want to compare two `int`s for example (`a` and `b`), and you write

```
return a - b;
```

it might overflow. If you convert them to doubles and use `(int)Math.signum( (double)a - (double)b )`, you will definitely avoid that. But there are simpler ways of achieving the same effect, `Integer.compare( a, b)` for example.